# NSDate from string giving wrong results

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to convert a string into an NSDate object.  I am using the following code to do the conversion:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:tz];

NSDate * dtEventStart = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"1/7/2013 6:30:00 AM"];
NSDate * dtEventEnd = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"1/7/2013 8:45:00 PM"];

NSLog(@"dtEventStart: %@", dtEventStart);
NSLog(@"dtEventEnd: %@", dtEventEnd);
```

However, the output looks like this:

```
dtEventStart: 2013-01-07 00:30:00 +0000
dtEventEnd: 2013-01-07 12:45:00 +0000
```

The output time and dates are not the same as the string that was used for the conversion.  I have also tried using EST for the timeZone but that produces different incorrect results as shown here:

```
dtEventStart: 2013-01-07 05:30:00 +0000
dtEventEnd: 2013-01-07 17:45:00 +0000
```

I know I am missing something, but I have no idea what. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

UPDATE:

Here is

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

EKEvent * eventForCalendar  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
eventForCalendar.title     = event.title;

NSDateFormatter * dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:tz];

NSDate * dtEventStart = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"1/7/2013 6:30:00 AM"];
NSDate * dtEventEnd = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"1/7/2013 8:45:00 PM"];

NSLog(@"dtEventStart: %@", dtEventStart);
NSLog(@"dtEventEnd: %@", dtEventEnd);

eventForCalendar.startDate = dtEventStart;
eventForCalendar.endDate = dtEventEnd;

[eventForCalendar setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:eventForCalendar span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

Comment: Is the computer you're running on in GMT?  You also said you see different results using EST but the output you have here is identical.

Comment: Sorry, cut/copy mistake... I have updated my post.

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: i am in EST, New Hampshire, USA

Comment: well, that explains the offset of five. `NSLog` prints the date it in UTC.

Comment: Watch out for daylight saving time, too.

Comment: No, I am sorry, I do not get it.  6:30 AM produces 5:30 and 4:45 PM produces 17:45, which is 5 hours, but wouldn't both times be 5 hours off.

Comment: both are five hours off. 00:30 to 05:30 in one case, then 12:45 to 17:45 in the other case. check @rdelmars answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Actually, I think you misread the post, my input string is 6:30:00 AM and the output was 00:30:00 which is 6 hours, and the end time input string was 8:45:00 PM and the output was 12:45.  That was when GMT was used.

Comment: You are right, I misread. I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing, the documentation recommends setting the *locale* of the date formatter to en_US_POSIX first:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW7

Also, this Q&A on Date formatters:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html

> I'm using NSDateFormatter to parse an Internet-style date, but this fails for some users in some regions. I've set a specific date format string; shouldn't that force NSDateFormatter to work independently of the user's region settings?
>
> No. While setting a date format string will appear to work for most users, it's not the right solution to this problem. There are many places where format strings behave in unexpected ways. For example:

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:-

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

NSDate * dtEventStart = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"1/7/2013 6:30:00 AM"];
NSDate * dtEventEnd = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"1/7/2013 8:45:00 PM"];

NSLog(@"dtEventStart: %@", dtEventStart);
NSLog(@"dtEventEnd: %@", dtEventEnd);
```

You will get following output with 24 hours format:-

```
dtEventStart: 2013-01-07 06:30:00 +0000
dtEventEnd: 2013-01-07 20:45:00 +0000
```